# IESDS on game with no strictly dominated strategies.

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am trying to figure out a question that involves using IESDS to removed the dominated strategies from a game in order to arrive at a Nash equilibrium. However, the problem in question does not appear to have any strictly dominated strategies that I could remove for either player, resulting in an infinite loop of turns. What part of IESDS am I missing that would allow me to solve it with IESDS?

Here is the game (`S` chooses columns, and `D` chooses rows):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check dominance by mixed strategies. For instance, for `S` a mixture of the last two columns dominates the second column.